# Using overridePendingTransition makes the calling activity disappear when new activity "pops" in in Android Kitkat?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

How do I stop this from happening? The calling activity disappears when the new acitivity "pops" in using overridePendingTransition. I am using overridePendingTransition so as to animate on older devices. I just need to stop the calling activity from disappearing like what I have done on LOLLIPOP devices

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = activity.getWindow();
    window.setExitTransition(null);
}
```

Take note this only happens on Android Kitkat 4.4.
I tried getting a Scene for the whole layout activity and then setting the exitAction to null but it didn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Did you ever find a solution?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't. I tried following one advice I read here on SO to use a different Theme than my main theme but it still doesn't work. I just created an animation that doesn't do anything and set an interval of 1000000 to keep it in place. And xml animations doesn't respect the repeatMode attribute so I can't make it repeat infinitely. If you do find anything please share it with me as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out the answer to this problem just now.

It seems like my theme attributes are messing up the animations. To solve this I had to set the following attributes:

```
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
```

which were originally:

```
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
```

After that, it worked properly on Kitkat and I tested on the other APIs and it still works as expected. I hope this helps someone else solving this issue